# javascript addEventListener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, click, action

I in this simple code there is something that interesting.

```js
  function run() {
 var btn = document.getElementById('run');
 function changeBg() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 }
 btn.addEventListener("click",changeBg,false);
}
```

```html
 <button id="run" onclick="run()">Run The Function</button>
```

When I click to the button the function doesn't work for first. it's working in the second click. I don't understand this. Can someone tell me why this happens ?

Comment: When is function run() called?

Answer (score 0):

**The Explanation:** When you're actually running the `run()` function, the eventListener is getting added to the button. That's why second time it works.

As the `run()` is not executed first there are no event listeners added to Button

Comment: yeah. do you have srcs for js ? I want to learn js in short time

Answer (score 0):

This is completely normal, you add the event listener in your run function so before that it won't be called since the event listener is not added yet.

```
function changeBg() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

<button id="run" onclick="changeBg()">Run The Function</button>
```

This is all you need.

Comment: did it. don't worry about that. :)

Comment: for everyone else. (y)

Answer (score 0):

```
var btn = document.getElementById('run');
btn.addEventListener("click",changeBg,false);

function changeBg() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

You are attaching the handler method in the run method. That is why the background changes to red the second time you click. Because the first time you click on it, the event handler method to change the background does not execute.

```
<button id="run" onclick="run()">Run The Function</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for 2 functions. Just call changeBg() directly.

In your case , your first run() call is initializing the event listener and second run() call is actually doing the work.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('run');
 
 function changeBg() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 }
 
btn.addEventListener("click",changeBg,false);
```

```html
 <button id="run" onclick="changeBg()">Run The Function</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only adding the event listener inside the function, so it works the second time, but not the first. This is very bad practice as the event listener will get added multiple times (one more time each time the button is clicked). You need to add the event listener when the DOM is ready. And since you're already adding an event listener for the click event, you don't need an inline click event handler (you should handle everything inside one event handler).

```html
<button id="run">Run The Function</button>
<script>
var btn = document.getElementById('run');
function changeBg() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
btn.addEventListener("click",changeBg,false);
</script>
```

If you want to toggle the background color, you should check the body's background color before changing it with a ternary operator.

```html
<button id="run">Run The Function</button>
<script>
var btn = document.getElementById('run');
function changeBg() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor == "red"?document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white":document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
btn.addEventListener("click",changeBg,false);
</script>
```

Comment: @Gaidant No problem.